# "Für einen Apfel und ein Ei." – Woher genau kommt diese Kombination?

Tags: etymology, idiom

> Für einen Apfel und ein Ei

Ich weiß, dass das im Endeffekt billig oder günstig bedeutet. Ich habe mir das aber ernährungstechnisch mal angeschaut und Apfel + Ei ist gar keine so schlechte Kombination.

Nun frage ich mich, ist der Ursprung dieser Redewendung nur der einfachen Verfügbarkeit und Billigkeit der beiden Lebensmittel geschuldet oder hat die Kombination Apfel + Ei noch andere positive Nebeneffekte?

Z. B.: Werden Äpfel und Eier oft zusammen gekauft/verwendet oder hat diese Kombi irgendeinen medizinischen Effekt (Hausmittel)?

Comment: Mal von Knuts Antwort abgesehen: Es ist ein pfanzliches und ein tierisches Produkt. Und beides sind von der Natur fertig produzierte Nahrungsmittel, d. h. der Bauer muss "nichts weiter" machen, als diese Produkte zu ernten und zu verkaufen. Getreide oder ein Schwein einfach so sind keine fertigen Nahrungsmittel. Butter und Marmelade sind verarbeitete Lebensmittel.

Answer (score 8):

> Sind Gegenstände in großen Mengen vorhanden, kosten sie meist nicht viel. Auf einem Bauernhof gibt es zum Beispiel viele Lebensmittel - wie Äpfel und Eier. Weil der Bauer davon ziemlich viele hat, kann er sie für einen geringen Preis verkaufen. Deshalb sagt man sprichwörtlich, wenn es irgendwo günstige Angebote gibt, dass sie für einen Apfel und ein Ei zu kaufen seien.

Source: http://www.geo.de/GEOlino/mensch/redewendungen/deutsch/fuer-n-appel-und-n-ei-50399.html

Similar explanation is on http://www.phraseo.de/phrase/fuer-einen-apfel-und-ein-ei/:

> Die Fügung stammt aus einer Zeit, als die Agrarwirtschaft noch vorherrschend war. Damals zählten Äpfel und Eier zu den Erzeugnissen, die auf Bauernhöfen reichlich vorhanden waren. Übergroßes Angebot führt bekanntlich zu niedrigen Preisen, ergo: Äpfel und Eier waren billig zu haben.